# How to return all documents using $group in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb pipleline that i'm building up. It's working fine, except that I have an issue in my group stage.

```
        'JURISDICTION'=>['$first'=> '$JURISDICTION'],
```

I'm only getting documents that match the first value, when they're are multiple values. Any ideas?

Comment: $first is supposed to only return the first value.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used `$first`, it will only return the first document, You can use `$push` to get all the records.

An Example:
For the database entry :

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:05:10Z") }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12Z") }
```

You can use this aggregation query which uses push

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: "$date"}, year: { $year: "$date" } },
           itemsSold: { $push:  { item: "$item", quantity: "$quantity" } }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

And the result is a list of items in itemSold

```
{
   "_id" : { "day" : 46, "year" : 2014 },
   "itemsSold" : [
      { "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 10 },
      { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10 },
      { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5 },
      { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 10 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : { "day" : 34, "year" : 2014 },
   "itemsSold" : [
      { "item" : "jkl", "quantity" : 1 },
      { "item" : "xyz", "quantity" : 5 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : { "day" : 1, "year" : 2014 },
   "itemsSold" : [ { "item" : "abc", "quantity" : 2 } ]
}
```

Reference: [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

Comment: @johnst123v If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.